# Passing client data to server-side methods

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, countdown

I have a JavaScript file that checks for bids using json data.

Now the problem I have is the plugin for the countdown has an onExpiry function that won't let you pass parameters, when u do the callback is called before the counter expires. On expiry of the countdown, it should set auction to Won, alert the user and add them to winners table. Most of this is handled by php, but the function I have made requires the auction_id and the username to be passed, but without passing parameters I cant think of how to do this. Here is the code I have at present.

Is Won PHP Function:

```
 function isWon($user, $auction){
        $this->load->model('Auction_model', 'Auction');
        $this->load->model('Bid_model', 'Bid');
        $this->load->model('Customer_model', 'Customer');

        $makeWon = $this->Auction->isWon($auction);
        $customer = $this->Customer->getByUsername($user);

        if ($makeWon){
            $json = array(
                'success' => 'Congratulations '.$user.' You have won.',
            );
        }

        echo json_encode($json);

    }
```

Common.Js

```
function checkBids(){

    var id = $('div.auction').attr('id'); 
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/tinybid/index.php/auction/auctiondata',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {

                $('#auction'+json[i]['i']+' li.user').html(json[i]['u']);
                $('#auction'+json[i]['i']+' li.curPrice').html(json[i]['p']);
                if (typeof json[i]['t'] =='number'){
                    $('#auction'+json[i]['i']+' li.timer').countdown({until: startTimer(json[i]['i'],json[i]['t']), onExpiry: isWon}); 
                }
            }
        }

    }); 
}
function startTimer(auction, stamp){
    var time= new Date();
    time.setTime(stamp*1000);
    $('#auction'+auction+' li.timer').countdown('change', {until: time}); 

}

function isWon(user, auction){
    if (user){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/tinybid/index.php/auction/isWon/'+user+'/'+auction,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json) {
                if (json['success']){   
                    alert(json['success'])
                }
            }

        }); 
    }
}
```

Here is the Json returned on the checkBids() function

```
[{"i":"5","t":1324374080,"p":"£ 0.13","u":"chrissy"}]
```

Is this the best way to create this countdown, or is the a better, cleaner way?
If this is the best way how can I get the functions to all work lol :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the "onExpiry" to let you pass parameters. 
First - you can alway to the function

```
onExpiry : function(){  isWon(user, auction); }
```

Thus effectively passing the arguments in the annonymous function implementation. 
But what I usually do is simply add a hidden input fields

```
<input id="user_id" type="hidden"/>
<input id="auction_id" type="hidden"/>
```

and in the "isWon" function - instead of getting "user" and "auction" as parameters simply do the following

```
var user_id = $("#user_id").val();
var auction_id =  $("#auction_id").val();
```

And then pass it in ajax to server, or directly pass it in ajax like so

```
 $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/tinybid/index.php/auction/isWon/'+user+'/'+auction,
            dataType: 'json',
            data:{user_id:$("#user_id").val(), auction_id:$("#auction_id").val()}, 
            success: function(json) {
                if (json['success']){   
                    alert(json['success'])
                }
            }
```

By the way - please note that the "URL" is weird in your example. Should start with "/" and not contain "index.php" in the middle. If I could have your file hierarchy I can resolve this too.